# Кандибобер

Tags: этимология

Пересмотрела несколько словарей в поисках этимологии слова *кандибобер*. Значение слова вопросов не вызывает. А вот откуда оно происходит? Может, кто-то просветит? Надеюсь на помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Не ищите. Версий много - достоверных нет.
Высказывалось предположение об искусственном окказиональном образовании, но оно опровергается широким распространением слова в южно-русских говорах (воронежском, донском, кубанском).
Встречается также вариант "синдибобер", что, видимо, говорит, о двухоcновности слова.

Comment: Есть еще и телебобер. Что же это за -бобер такой? :-))